# Displaying children in a grid with Dojo 1.7

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

I'd like to display some data in a tree/grid format like so:

```
MasterId     Title                       Date
  DetailId
  DetailId
MasterId     Title                       Date
  DetailId
```

where the IDs, title, and date are separate columns, and the DetailIDs are children of a MasterId. When the user clicks on a detail line, I'll perform an action. If the user sorts a column, I'd like the DetailIds to stay with their parent MasterId.

Is there a way to do this with stock Dojo components? The dojox.grid.TreeGrid looks close, but from what I can tell when you expand the children, the DetailIds will go into their own column, where I'd prefer they stay in the same column as MasterId.

If there's not an out-of-the-box way to do this, should I try subclassing a TreeGrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that a dojox.grid.TreeGrid is what I was looking for, but I didn't know about dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel. This example does exactly what I'm trying to do:

http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/test_treegrid_model.html